# Expresso Store - Total sales in template

Tags: expresso-store

I am running a ticket sales setup with store for an online event and would like to display the total number of products sold via a template to feed a live display of total tickets sold, is there any way for me to display the total number of products sold?

Currently I could display ALL products sold and not just a set of products, but in the future dates spans as well as specific products would be nice to define.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the total number of a certain product sold, you can do that using EE's built in [query module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/query/) and a bit of SQL:

```
select sum(item_qty) as qty_sold
from exp_store_order_items
join exp_store_orders on exp_store_order_items.order_id = exp_store_orders.id
where order_completed_date > 0
  and entry_id = 123
```

**Note:** if you are using Store 1.6 you will need to replace `exp_store_orders.id` above with `exp_store_orders.order_id`.